# how do i delete what i printed already so i want to show the user answer for couple second and delete it

Tags: python

```
import os
from time import sleep

os.chdir(path="C:\\all\\guessing")
data = open("data.txt", "r")

q = 1 
r = 1
w = 0
e = 0
t = 
y = 0

s = 1 
d = 1
g = 1
a = 0
f = 0
h = 0

z = 0
x = 0
c = 0
b = 0
v = 1
n = 1

gridd = '''
q w e r t y
a s d f g h
z x c v b n
'''
answer = '''
1 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 1
'''

def checker():
  pass

time = 7
while True:
    print("try to avoid 0")
    print("O = '1' , X = '0'")
    sleep(4)
    print(answer)
    sleep(time)
    print(gridd)


    #if correct:
    #time = time - 1
    if time == 0:
    print("wow you made it to the end nice")
```

so at line 40 i just want to show them the answer for 7 seccond and dont show them how do i do that and if if there is any ways 
to make some code shorter that would be awesome

Comment: sorry this is my first time using this

Comment: dont copy the code line numbers, paste the code in your question and mark it and press ctrl+K to format it

Comment: Please [edit] your question to properly show the code. Note that removing output may depend on your system (Windows, Unix, ...).

Comment: why is t unassigned? `t = `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cls` command on Windows and `clear` in Linux/Unix to clear the entire screen, if it satisfies your requirement:

```
from os import name, system
if name == 'nt':
  system('cls')
else:
  system('clear')
```

The `system` method executes commands you can run in your system's command line interface.